# Actuary expected value question (car battery)

Tags: probability, expectation

A new car battery is sold for 100 with a 3-year limited warranty. If the battery fails at time *t* (0<*t*<3), the battery manufacture will refund 100(1-*t*/3). After analyzing the battery performance, the battery manufacturer uses the continuous uniform distribution on the interval (0,*n*) as the model for time until failure of the battery (*n* years). The battery manufacturer determines that the expected cost of the warranty is 10. Find *n*.

So the answer in the book is simply $\int_0^3100(1-t/3)\cdot\frac1n dt=10$ (solve for n)

However, I don't understand why they are integrating in terms of *t* since isn't $f(n)=\frac1n$ therefore, in my mind, it should be

$E(N)=\int_0^3100(1-t/3)\cdot\frac1n dn$ (range 0<$n$<3 since if $t>0$ no payment)

Comment: The expected cost has to be with respect to $t$ because it is the value of $t$ that depends whether or not the manufacturer has to pay out. The  expected amount that has to be paid out is solely determined over the interval $(0,3)$, i.e. the value of $t$. This ought to make sense; if instead the company is looking at an expected pay out of $100$dollar, your answer for $n$ would be 1.5 years, which is exactly in the middle of the warranty period, as expected with an uniform distribution.

Comment: But doesn't the value of $n$ that determines whether the manufacturer pays out? As in the manufacturer only pays out if the battery fails and the probability of the battery failing is $1/n$.

Comment: $n$ is a constant.  It's value is unknown, but it doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The failure time $T$ is a random variable.  The support's upper bound $n$ is a constant.

You do not integrate with respect to constants; they have only one value.

The expectation is a weighted integral of the function over the support with respect to the random variable.

$$\begin{split}\mathsf E(N(T)) &=\int_0^n N(t)~ f_T(t)~\mathsf d t \\ 10 & = \int_0^{\min(3,n)} 100(1-t/3)\cdot~\tfrac 1n~\mathsf d t\\&= 15\end{split}$$

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: That's a better explanation.